# iOS view offset after youTube video execution

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I am calling a youtube channel on a `UIWebView`. When user selects a video, device launches its video player as normal. However, when video ends or user finishes it returning to view, an offset is applied to whole app!! All views have an offset on top but this only happens on iPad and iPad simulator with compatibility mode, on iPhone and iPhone simulator not! How to solve it? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you hide the status bar in your application?

Comment: looks suspiciously status bar sized...

Comment: I have noticed a similar bug appear (seemingly) randomly in the official Twitter app. I think it may be more of a OS bug than something in your code.

Comment: I am not hidding the status bar but seems that this is the problem. When iPhone compatibility mode on iPad, a black stripe is reserved for the toolbar and after video execution dissapears

Comment: @Jeremy yes, seems that it is a bug. Well, when executing [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; problem is beeing solved, now I must capture event when video player end or is stopped. Any idea? Thanks

Comment: NSNotificationCenter does the trick! thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that status bar dissapears after video execution.

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` problem is beeing solved when an event is fired using `NSNotificationCenter`